# How can I get the data in the radio button even if it is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a questionnaire function, the problem that I am getting is I need to submit
all of their answer even if the radio is button is not checked.

This is the sample HTML:

```js
$('input:radio').each(function () {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    answers.push({
        question_id: $(this).attr("data-question_id"),
        answer_id: ($(this).val()== "" || $(this).val() == undefined) ? 0 : $(this).val(),
        answer_text: ($(this).parent().find('span').text()== "") ? 0 : $(this).parent().find('span').text(),
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 2
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 3
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 4
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 5
</div>


<div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 6
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 7
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 8
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 9
</div>

<div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 10
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 11
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 12
 <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 13
</div>
```

I can already get the value of all checked radio button when submitting but I also want to push all of the unchecked unique radio input in my `answers` array when the user submit their answer. for instance if the user Didn’t answer, I just need to save the `data-question_id` so I can know what question is not answered at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code you will get two aarays on submit.

```js
$(".submit_ans").on('click', function() {
    var answers = [];
    var attempted_ques  = [];
    var not_attempted_ques  = [];
    $('input:radio').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            answers.push({
                question_id: $(this).attr("data-question_id"),
                answer_id: ($(this).val()== "" || $(this).val() == undefined) ? 0 : $(this).val(),
                answer_text: ($(this).parent().find('span').text()== "") ? 0 : $(this).parent().find('span').text(),
            });
            attempted_ques.push($(this).attr("data-question_id"));
        }
        else
        {
            not_attempted_ques.push($(this).attr("data-question_id"));
        }
    });

    function uniqueArr(value, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }

    not_attempted_ques = not_attempted_ques.filter(uniqueArr);
    not_attempted_ques = not_attempted_ques.filter(function(val) {
        return attempted_ques.indexOf(val) == -1;
    });
    console.log('Attempted Questions => '+attempted_ques);
    console.log('Not Attempted Questions => '+not_attempted_ques);
});

$(".reset_ans").on('click', function() {
    $('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 2
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 3
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 4
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 5
</div>


<div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 6
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 7
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 8
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 9
</div>

<div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 10
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 11
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 12
    <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 13
</div>

<button class="submit_ans">Submit</button>
<button class="reset_ans">Reset</button>
```

Comment: this helped me a lot, I was able to get the idea based on your answer and managed to create my own style of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a variable to store all question is answered or not.

```
  var allAnswer = {};

  $('input:radio').each(function () {
    let question_id = $(this).attr("data-question_id");
    if (!Object.keys(allAnswer).includes(question_id)) {
         allAnswer[question_id] = false;
    }
     
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      allAnswer[question_id] = true;
      
      answers.push({
          question_id: $(this).attr("data-question_id"),
          answer_id: ($(this).val()== "" || $(this).val() == undefined) ? 0 : $(this).val(),
          answer_text: ($(this).parent().find('span').text()== "") ? 0 : $(this).parent().find('span').text(),
      });
    }
  });
```

If `allAnswer[i]` is `true` means question `i` is answered, else `false` means it is NOT checked by radio

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values in a textarea element

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 2
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 3
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 4
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='1' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_0'>test 5
           </div>
           
           
           <div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 6
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 7
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 8
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='2' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_1'>test 9
           </div>
           
           <div class='question_choices_wrapper'>
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="2" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 10
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="3" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 11
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="4" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 12
            <input type='radio' data-question_id='3' class='choices_settings' value="5" name='scenario_question_choices_2'>test 13
           </div>

           <!-- CHANGE TO visibility:hidden IN PRODUCTION -->
           <textarea name="allInputsRadio" width="800" height="800" style="visibility:visible"> </textarea> 
    </form>

    <script>
        const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
        const allInputsRadio = [...document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]')]
        textarea.value =''
        allInputsRadio.forEach(e => {
            textarea.value += `data-question_id: ${e.getAttribute('data-question_id')} value: ${e.getAttribute('value')}  name: ${e.getAttribute('name')}\n`
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Results]